# sidebar advert with incorrect link

Tags: support, open-source-advertising

The advert in the screenshot below appeared on superuser.com but the link does not match the text of the advert:

[image: advert]

The text of the advert is "Question of the Week: What causes a computer to overheat? -nute   superuser Community Blog"

The link is: [QotW: If a password is compromised, are any similar ones?](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/27/qotw-if-a-password-is-compromised-are-any-similar-ones/)

Comment: The correct link might be this: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/07/11/what-makes-a-computer-overheat/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily fixed: on Meta Super User look for tag `community-ads`, and you'll find [the ad](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2164/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011/2280#2280).

I've changed the link into the one you found. Not sure how quickly that will catch up.